# Python to extract output from attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-gitlab

I am trying to extract the specific details like `authored_date` from the attribute which I am getting with help of python.

What is my end goal:

I want to extract the specific branches which are named as `tobedeleted_branch1`, `tobedeleted_branch2` and delete them with help of my script if the `authored_date` is more than 7 days.

I am beginner in this and learning this currently.

So, what I want to do is,

Extract the authored date from the output and check if it is older than 7 days.
If it is older than 7 days I will go ahead and perform whatever I want to perform in if condition.

```
import gitlab, os
#from gitlab.v4.objects import *
# authenticate
TOKEN = "MYTOKEN"
GITLAB_HOST = 'MYINSTANCE' # or your instance
gl = gitlab.Gitlab(GITLAB_HOST, private_token=TOKEN)

# set gitlab group id
group_id = 6
group = gl.groups.get(group_id, lazy=True)

#get all projects
projects = group.projects.list(include_subgroups=True, all=True)

#get all project ids
project_ids = []
for project in projects:
#    project_ids.append((project.path_with_namespace, project.id, project.name ))
    project_ids.append((project.id))
print(project_ids)

for project in project_ids:
    project = gl.projects.get(project)
    branches = project.branches.list() 
    for branch in branches:
       if "tobedeleted" in branch.attributes['name']:
           print(branch.attributes['name'])
           #print(branch)
           print(branch.attributes['commit'])
           #branch.delete()
```

The output which I am getting from printing the `print(branch.attributes['commit'])` is like :

```
{'id': '1245829930', 'short_id': '124582', 'created_at': '2021-11-15T09:10:26.000+00:00', 'parent_ids': None, 'title': 'branch name commit' into \'master\'"', 'message': 'branch name commit', 'author_name': 'Administrator', 'author_email': 'someemail@gmail.com', 'authored_date': '2021-11-15T09:10:26.000+00:00', 'committer_name': 'Administrator', 'committer_email': 'someemail@gmail.com', 'committed_date': '2021-11-15T09:10:26.000+00:00', 'trailers': None, 'web_url': 'someweburl'}
```

From the above output, I want to extract the 'authored_date' and check if it is greated than 7 days I will go ahead and delete the merged branch.

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing in this question that is about Git or GitLab, it's all about the Python interface. The one thing I would note that *is* a Git/GitLab thing is that the "branch commit date" is the date on the *tip commit* of the branch. As the branch name is altered to point to different commits, you'll pick up each commit's information.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
created_at = '2021-11-15T09:10:26.000+00:00'
t = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(created_at)
n = datetime.datetime.now(tz=t.tzinfo)

if n - t <= datetime.timedelta(days=7):
    ... # do someting
```

Comment: Why not `timedelta(days=7)` ?

Comment: we should pass timezone to datetime.datetime.now() to get correct current datetime and hence day difference

Comment: @aberry you are right

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Vassago but one thing I forgot to mention is that, the authored date will be different for every other branch. 
So I can not hardcode that specific date.

Comment: @SameerAtharkar It's an example, you may replace `created_at ` and  `days` to with what you want

Answer (score 0):

using your `branch.attributes` about your commit inside your loop, you can do the following (make sure you import datetime). You'll want to append the branch name to be deleted to a list that you'll iterate over after, as you do not want to modify any object that you are currently iterating over (IE deleting items from the `branches` object that you are still iterating over).

```
from datetime import datetime

...
branches_to_delete = []
for project in project_ids:
    project = gl.projects.get(project)
    branches = project.branches.list() 
    for branch in branches:
       if "tobedeleted" in branch.attributes['name']:
           print(branch.attributes['name'])
           #print(branch)
           print(branch.attributes['commit'])
           branch_date_object = datetime.strptime((branch.attributes['commit']['authored_date'].split('.')[0]), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
           days_diff = datetime.now() - branch_date_object
           if days_diff.days > 7:
               branches_to_delete.append(branch.attributes['name'])

for branch in branches_to_delete:
    # perform your delete functionality
```

Comment: I am getting the name error as : 

`branch_date_object = datetime.strptime((mydict['commit']['authored_date'].split('.')[0]), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") NameError: name 'mydict' is not defined`

Comment: sorry @SameerAtharkar, mydict should be `branch.attributes` I just was testing on my end. I have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
def get_day_diff(old_date):
    old_datetime = datetime.fromisoformat(old_date)
    # Check timezone of date
    tz_info = old_datetime.tzinfo
    current_datetime = datetime.now(tz_info)
    datetime_delta = current_datetime - old_datetime
    return datetime_delta.days

# test with authored_date
authored_date = '2021-11-15T09:10:26.000+00:00'
if get_day_diff(authored_date) > 7:
  # then delete branch
  branch.delete()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @aberry but one thing I forgot to mention is that, the authored date will be different for every other branch. So I can not hardcode that specific date

Comment: @SameerAtharkar I am not hard coding date here. It is just a example to test get_day_diff method. You will use above method for 'branch.attributes['commit']['authored_date']' in your code